# CakePHP 2 pagination gives 404 address not found error

Tags: cakephp, pagination, runtime-error

I am developing an application with CakePHP 2.3 and am having a problem with pagination. When I click on any of the pagination links I am getting a /cab/ServiceDirectory/refine/page:2 (or which ever link) was not found on this server. If I go to /cab/ServiceDirectory/refine I see the pagination links showing there should be 5 pages. If I remove the pagination code from the controller and the view I see all the results I should see.

In my ServiceDirectoryResultsController I have

```
public function index() {
  $this->ServiceLocation->recursive=0;
}

public function refine ($id=null) (

 // All my code to get the ServiceLocations from the DB

$this->paginate->array(
  'conditions' => array('ServiceLocation.state' => $states[$state], 'ServiceLocation.solution_categories' => $active_cat),
  'limit' => 8,
);

$results = $this->paginate('ServiceLocation');
$this->set('serviceLocation' ,$results);

}
```

In my View I have

```
<div class="paging">
  <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
  ?>
</div>

<?php foreach ($serviceLocation as $Location): ?>

  // I echo a few things from the $Location array

<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="paging">
  <?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class' => 'prev disabled'));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array('separator' => ''));
    echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >', array(), null, array('class' => 'next disabled'));
  ?>
</div>
```

Without the paging and use doing  a find all and sending that to the view I see the 40 results I would expect.

With the pagination in I see the pagination links and if I hover over them I see my url /cab/ServiceDirectoryResults/refine/page:2 or page:3 or page:4 or page:5

If I click on any of these links with the :pageX on them I get an error

Error: The requested address '/cab/ServiceDirectoryResults/refine/page:2 was not found on this server'

I have done a lot of reading about the CakePHP paging and can not find any reason for this behaviour. Can anyone suggest a reason or a possible solution or a path to follow to debug this error?

Regards

Richard

I checked the error level and it was already set to level 2

Here is the last entry in the error log

```
2013-05-22 17:09:28 Error: [NotFoundException] Not Found
Request URL: /cab/ServiceDirectoryResults/refine/page:2
Stack Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/cab/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(1074): PaginatorComponent->paginate('ServiceLocation', Array, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/cab/app/Controller/ServiceDirectoryResultsController.php(381): Controller->paginate('ServiceLocation')
#2 [internal function]: ServiceDirectoryResultsController->refine()
#3 /var/www/html/cab/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(486): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(ServiceDirectoryResultsController), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/cab/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(187): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#5 /var/www/html/cab/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(162): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(ServiceDirectoryResultsController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#6 /var/www/html/cab/app/webroot/index.php(109): Dispatcher-   >dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#7 {main}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: In app/Config/core.php you will be able to see debug. Set the value to 2 and see what is the error.

Comment: I had to answer in by editing the original post because it will not let me answer my own post for 8 hours and the error message was too long for a comment

Comment: public function refine ($id=null) the bracket after this should be a curly brackt. do not use $results = $this->paginate('ServiceLocation'); If you model is ServiceLocation simple use $this->paginate();

Comment: If I change the $this->paginate('ServiceLocation'); to just $this->paginate(); I get an error that the table service_directory_results for model ServiceDirectorResults does not exist. The model I am using is ServiceLocation and I loaded that earlier in the function with a $this->loadModel('ServiceLocation');

The missing curly bracket on the refine function was a typo when I copied from my development box

Comment: Have you tried to remove the optional `$id=null` parameter from your `refine()` action? Or are you using that? If so, please add the code that uses that $id

Comment: The $id=null has been removed. It was left over from some earlier development and should have been long gone. I made no difference removing it

Comment: Have you made changes to routes.php?

Comment: No the routes.php has not been touched at all

Answer (score 6):

FYI: I'm using Cakephp 2.4, I've only tested it on this version.

I ran into this same issue. I store the pagination variables in the user's session.
This way when a user navigates away from a page, they don't loose their place (page/sort field/direction) when they come back to the page.

Because I store the variables in the session, then retrieve them from the session, if say the user clicks on a link that causes the results to be less then the page they were on, I'll get a 404.

Example (The page they were on):
    `http://localhost/products/index/page:5/sort:Product.name`

I send them this link:
    `http://localhost/products/index/search:[search_term]`

This filters the results to only 2 pages.
 In this case, actual (perma)link, with the session variables restored, would look like:
    `http://localhost/products/index/page:5/sort:Product.name/search:[search_term]`

Page 5 is out of the scope of the 2 pages from the new results.
This will throw the `NotFoundException();` seen here:
    http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-PaginatorComponent.html#238

How I resolved this was to catch the exception, then redirect them to the first page.
Since all of the pagination variables (including the 'search') are stored in the session, I only need to pass the page variable:

Example:
    `http://localhost/products/index/page:1`

Cakephp recommended this as a possible way to overcome it:
    http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#out-of-range-page-requests

However, I wanted this available for all of my 'index' pages, so I overwrote the `Controller::paginate()` method in the `AppController`.
Original paginate method seen here:
    http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#1070-1081

Here is how I did it in my *Controller/AppController.php*:

```
<?php

class CommonAppController extends Controller
{
    // ..... other code
    public function paginate($object = null, $scope = array(), $whitelist = array())
    {
    /*
     * Used to see if we get an exception thrown, 
     * If so, send them to the first page, and set the flash so they know
     */
        try
        {
            // taken from their current paginate();
            // http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-class-Controller.html#1070-1081
            return $this->Components->load('Paginator', $this->paginate)->paginate($object, $scope, $whitelist);
        }
        catch (NotFoundException $e)
        {
            //Do something here like redirecting to first or last page.
            //$this->request->params['paging'] will give you required info.
            $page = (isset($this->request->params['named']['page'])?$this->request->params['named']['page']:1);

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to find results on page: %s. Redirected you to page 1.', $page));
            return $this->redirect(array('page' => 1));
        }
    }
    // ..... other code
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

8 months later...I just bumped into the same issue, and thought I could leave my findings here to avoid somebody else spending a couple of hours looking for a solution like I have been.

I had the same issue as Richard, when a GET request onto any other link of the pagination split bar, from 2 to n, was to generate a 404 error.
This 404 error originates from the PaginatorComponent (CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/PaginatorComponent.php), in these lines:

```
$pageCount = intval(ceil($count / $limit));
$requestedPage = $page;
$page = max(min($page, $pageCount), 1);

if ($requestedPage > $page) {
  throw new NotFoundException();
}
```

In a nutshell, this happens when the predicative **conditions** member has become so restrictive as to create a much smaller recordset than for page #1.

What can create this is that it now contains **more** predicates in it, that you just do not want. A way to see what it contains for page #2+ is to add this call:

```
FirePHP($parameters);
```

just before the lines above. You may be surprised.

The question is "why does **conditions**, that you should build in your controller and pass to the find() method, has changed so much from page #1 that works, to page #2+ that does not?
I cannot just answer for you without seing the rest of your code, but I can tell you what was happening for my case:
I was storing some values in $_SESSION so that my search could be remembered, and I was relying on isset($this->request->data[$objectName]) to know if I should add that particular predicate to my 'conditions' array. But that was without thinking that only **page #1** is the result of a **POST method**, not the subsequent paginated requests pages, which are got through **GET** method. Therefore from page #2 onwards, $this->request->data[$objectName] is empty, but SESSION was still set because I had forgottent to reset it.

The conclusion is: remember page #2+ calls are GET, and the request data that you may have used and were working for POST are no more valid, creating a different set of conditions now, reducing your recordset, and creating a total count that may be 0, voiding the pagination system, hence the 404.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue for CakePHP3. The quickest way to solve is to change the form action so that it do not grab the "?page=x" part of the URL. For example, change it to current page URL like

```
<form action="<?=\Cake\Core\Configure::::read('App.domain')?>/page_url" ...
```